# How to dual boot Ubuntu without USB or CD/DVD?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, lenovo, windows-10

I have Windows 10(preinstalled) and now I want to dual boot it with Ubuntu. I don't have USB or CD/DVD, so how can I dual boot it. Still now I try to use Unetbootin and Linuxlive USB Creator, but both of them don't work.
I can't use VM because I have a low end pc. I have low RAM and the processer is also not too much good but yes I don't have any type of problem with ROM
Please help me...

Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Twitter, or Facebook.

Comment: Help me please...

Comment: You are essentially asking us "*I set fire to my building. How will I escape?*" Ubuntu is designed by the developers to be installed using the USB or CD/DVD. It's possible other ways, but those ways are frustrating and painful for a beginner. Advice: Borrow a friend's (blank) USB stick, and use it to install the normal way.

Comment: I have a lot of friends in school but in the place where I live I don't any friend or any one from whom I can get a USB...
And for Covid-19 our school is close for last 1 year.

Comment: I think you understand my situation...

Comment: Do you know that recent Windows 10 releases may have a built-in "emulated" Linux environment? Or if it's not present in your release, then it can be installed? It can at least show you a linux command line environment, where you can learn/practice linux commands, and even install and run some command-line-interface oriented applications. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there's no way that I (and probably anyone else for that matter) know of to install Ubuntu without needing a USB stick or other form of installation media, so your best bet is to wait until you get some form of installation media.

Also, if you have a low end computer, I wouldn't recommend normal Ubuntu, since the Gnome desktop enviroment is pretty resource heavy. Instead I would recommend some other Ubuntu flavour with a lighter desktop enviroment, like Xubuntu or Lubuntu.